# Convert Html to a Printable Image

Tags: html, image, printing, .net-2.0

I am working on a project which runs on .NET 2.0. My task is to recreate the data displayed in HTML as a prinatable image (with the resolution of at least 150dpi). I looked into several options, to no avail:

1. The [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class object. While rendering html as an image, it uses the screen resolution on the server machine.
2. The [Sciter](http://www.terrainformatica.com/sciter/main.whtm) by Terra Informatica. It does not exposes a property with which one can set the resolution of the output image
3. [Awesomium](http://awesomium.codeplex.com) can be used with .NET 4.0 or higher only.

I wonder if there is a .NET library out there that can convert an Html page to a printable image.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to [generate the page as a PDF server-side](http://www.aspose.com/.net/pdf-component.aspx?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=pdf.net) an allow the user to download and print the PDF.