# Convert HTML to TIFF or printable poster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, printing, tiff

I want to make a website that people come and type a sentence and I make a poster out of it, print it, and send it to them.

I know I can make a box with html divs and color it and put some web font, but My questions are:

- How do I go from HTML to TIFF ( I've read TIFF is the best format for poster print)
- given that dpi on web is a lot lower than posters, how do I increase the dpi on generating the poster? Can I use some sort of library on the server?
- What are the drawbacks of using web fonts? if they have large enough font size?
- Also how do companies like zazzle, mixbook, shutterfly go about putting font on the image and printing it large?
- My Original plan was to use Rails, are there any useful Gems that can help me?
- I see [Convert Html to a Printable Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610631/convert-html-to-a-printable-image) people advice converting to PDF, wouldn't it destroy the quality of the poster?

Any other advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be useful for you https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit
And look at http://www.imagemagick.org/- for image processing. It has ruby wrapper http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/